# Executing stored procedure in PHP : ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

Executing stored procedure in PHP gives ORA-01460. 
This is the simplified(original has over 48 input values) code in php:

```
$proc_sql = "BEGIN CREATE_RECORD(:b1, :b2, :b3, :b4, :b5, :b6); END;";

$bind = array("bind 1", "bind 2", "bind 3", "bind 4", "bind 5", "OUT DUMMY");

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $proc_sql);

$i = 1;

$outval = "";

foreach($bind as $val){
    $tmp =":b".$i;
    if($i < count($bind)){
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,$tmp,$val);
    }else{
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $tmp, $outval, 512);
    }
    $i++;
}
oci_execute($stmt);
```

Last line produces the warning. However if I run query directly in SQL Developer:

```
declare
    re varchar2(512);
begin

CREATE_RECORD('bind 1', 'bind 2', 'bind 3', 'bind 4', 'bind 5', re);
dbms_output.put_line(re);

end;
```

Insert is completed successfully.
It's my first project with PHP & Oracle combination. So I don't know if my php is incorrect or the problem lies elsewhere.
Here is OCI8 info from `phpinfo()`:

```
oci8

OCI8 Support    enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support disabled
OCI8 Version    2.0.8
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  10.2.0.3.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version  10.2

Directive                        Local Value             Master Value

oci8.default_prefetch                100                     100
oci8.events                          Off                     Off
oci8.max_persistent                   -1                      -1
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics         Off                     Off
oci8.persistent_timeout               -1                      -1
oci8.ping_interval                    60                      60
oci8.privileged_connect              Off                     Off
oci8.statement_cache_size             20                      20
```

`PHP Version 5.5.17` and `Oracle 9i`
Please, help find out why am I getting this warning.
Thank you for reading.

**UPDATE**

The code below also works:

```
$proc_sql = "BEGIN CREATE_RECORD('bind 1', 'bind 2', 'bind 3', 'bind 4', 'bind 5', :b6); END;";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $proc_sql);
$outval = "";
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':b6', $outval, 512);
```

As I said above, this is simplified version of executing procedure code, in reality I need to bind 48 parameters IN and one OUT parameter. Does it have to do something with `statement_cache_size` in OCI8 settings ?
I've read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.configuration.php#ini.oci8.statement-cache-size) but can't really understand if it has anything to do with my problem.

Comment: Can you please share the code of the `CREATE_RECORD` procedure as well so that we can see what actually happens within there. I assume that the 6th parameter is an OUT variable but that's just a guess based on the "OUT DUMMY" value for the 6th bind variable.

Comment: Hi gvenzl, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I cannot show the inner part of the procedure since I don't have the permission, and yes, the 6th parameter is an out variable. If you'd look at `foreach` loop there is `else` block where I bind out variable. I also found out that if I insert values  directly into the query, the procedure works... Please see my update.

Comment: Did you try to display the statement once binded? What does it give?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, how did you resolve this ?

Comment: Your use of a literal placeholder for the last parameter then skipping to binding the OUT variable confuses the logic of your code greatly. You might consider starting by unrolling the loop completely and having 5 binds to an inline literal and one to the OUT variable. You should also consider testing with a single parameter proc for each of IN and OUT

Answer (score 1):

Please, see [this piece of PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php), especially this part:

> A bind call tells Oracle which memory address to read data from. For
>   IN binds that address needs to contain valid data when oci_execute()
>   is called. This means that the variable bound must remain in scope
>   until execution. If it doesn't, unexpected results or errors such as
>   "ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested" may
>   occur. For OUT binds one symptom is no value being set in the PHP
>   variable.

If I undestand your code well, you use a local variable inside a loop to cycle through your IN parameters, so you do not satisfy the demand to have all the values in scope when you call oci_execute after the cycle is completed.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have problems when binding parameters inside a `for-each` loop keep reading.

One of the answers [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) has the following comment, inside a sample code snippet which says about binding parameters inside a loop - which makes sense.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) { 
   // oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $val) does not work
   // because it binds each placeholder to the same location: $val
   // instead use the actual location of the data: $arr[$key]
}
```

According to the above statement, the following **DO NOT** work,

```
$arr = array(':a' => 1, ':b' => 2);
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {    
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $val);
}
```

The following **DO** work,

```
$arr = array(':a' => 1, ':b' => 2);
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {    
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $arr[$key]);
}
```

I hope someone will find this useful :)